# Is there a way to pivot a datetime column in a dataframe into columns with the months with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the next problem with a dataframe

| Product | Arrive Time |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 2021-1-25 |
| 00002 | 2021-2-25 |
| 00003 | 2021-3-25 |
| 00001 | 2021-4-25 |
| 00002 | 2021-4-25 |
| 00003 | 2021-3-10 |

Like this I have a lot of entries.
It is possible to pivot o to split the column arrive Time into months, to have something like this?

| Product | January | February | March | April |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Yes | na | na | yes |
| 00002 | na | yes | na | yes |
| 00003 | na | na | yes | na |

Answer (score 1):

Use `crosstab`:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df['Product'], df['Arrive Time'].dt.strftime('%B')) \
      .astype(bool).replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'na'})

Arrive Time April February January March
Product                                 
1             Yes       na     Yes    na
2             Yes      Yes      na    na
3              na       na      na   Yes
```

Comment: Great!! Thats exactly what I need it, Thanks